# Powershell Script to get Count from List with filter

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

Powershell script to get Count from SharePoint List

The following code works fine. It grabs data from a SharePoint list "Assignment Status" and display the results in csv file export. I want it to display the count. I was the output to show 2 columns: AssignedToPerson and the Count.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "https://dev1.spr.com/sites/tech/"
#Get the Target List

$list = $web.Lists["Pending Assignments"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()
 $list.Items |  Where-Object { $_["Assignment Status"] -eq "Pending"} | foreach {
 $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
#Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html#ixzz5uQEppUXH
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AssignedPerson" -value $_["AssignedPerson"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "TotalCountofPendingItems" -value $_["Count"]
 #Add the object with property to an Array
 $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
 #Export the result Array to CSV file
 $ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "c:\dev1scripts\Exportfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation                       
#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
#Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html#ixzz5uQ8WDlpQ
```

Results should be like the following:

```
"Jonathan Adams", 3
"Roger Smith", 5
"Candice Matthews", 19
```

and so on...

Comment: What's wrong on `Write-Output $ListItemCollection`?

Comment: The code runs fine. There is no error. I want to add a column with the count. Please post the revised code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the PowerShell as below.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "https://dev1.spr.com/sites/tech/"
#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["Pending Assignments"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()
$ItemCount=0;
$TotalCount=0;
$list.Items |  Where-Object { $_["Assignment Status"] -eq "Pending"} | foreach {
    $ItemCount++
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AssignedPerson" -value $_["AssignedPerson"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TotalCountofPendingItems" -value $_["Count"]
    $TotalCount+=$_["Count"]
    #Add the object with property to an Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}
$ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AssignedPerson" -value "Total:$ItemCount"
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TotalCountofPendingItems" -value "Total:$TotalCount"
$ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "c:\dev1scripts\Exportfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation                       
#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```

The results:

[image]

Comment: The total count is showing correctly but the individual count is blank. Results: "Jonathan Adams", "Roger Smith", "Candice Matthews"

Comment: Did you have the individual count field "Count" in list items?